Capture video of my screen with libpipewire
The pipewire example has an example of capturing video from a webcam https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/tree/0.3.45/src/examples. The window that opens displays video from the webcam. How to capture video from the desktop, not from the camera? That is, so that my screen would be broadcast into the window.
I tried to replace here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/blob/0.3.45/src/examples/video-play.c#L469 Camera with Screen, but the video from the camera is still broadcast, not from the desktop
